# change exist commit to current commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

Simply, I've done like this :

```
A------B-------C
        \
         \
          B2
```

Now, I want to change B to B2.

```
A------B2-------C
```

Is it possible?

**SOLUTION HISTORY:**

I just added my work history.

```
$ git log
commit b671c70b C
commit f4acdc2b B
commit 56f38939 A

$ git checkout f4acdc2b
```

and I modified something... then committed with -amend option.

```
$ git commit -amend
$ git log
commit e2fd729 B'
commit 56f3893 A
```

Now, It became like this:

```
A------B-------C
        \
         \
          B'
```

To rebasing B to B'

```
$ git checkout b671c70b
$ git rebase -i 56f38939
```

which opens the interactive editor

```
pick f4acdc2b B
pick 56f38939 A
```

just remove line `pick f4acdc2b`, save and quit.

If there is error `error: could not apply b671c70b... C`,
edit all merge conflicts and then,

```
$ git add .
$ git rebase --continue

$ git log
commit 914c6bc C'
commit 56f3893 A

$ git checkout 914c6bc
$ git rebase e2fd729 
$ git log
commit 5c65190 C''
commit e2fd729 B'
commit 56f3893 A
```

Now, It looks like this.

```
A------B'-------C''
```

Comment: You'd have to change the SHAs for both B2 and C via rebasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could interactively rebase your branch on top of `B2` (on top of `A` actually, since you want `B2` gone):

```
 git checkout yourBranch # which references C)
 git rebase -i A
 # drop B
```

That would give:

```
 A------B2'-------C'
```

(note that `C'` is `C` with a different SHA1, since its parent has changed)
(Same comment for `B2`, since its parent also changed)

Comment: But in this case `B` will remain in the history. The resulting repository will look like `A-------B------B2-------C'`, doesn't it?

Comment: @RenéLink True: I have edited the answer to add the interactive part of the rebase

Answer (score 3):

To completely remove `B` you must re-integrate `B2` on `A` and `C` on `B2`.

```
git checkout C
git rebase B2
```

This rebases branch `C` on top of `B2`

```
A-------B------B2-------C'
```

(note that C' is a new commit)

But now you still have the `B` commit in the history. You can remove it with an interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i A
```

which opens the interactive editor

```
pick 05c98ef B
pick e31d9f0 B2
pick 5d30d05 C
```

just remove line `pick 05c98ef B`, save and quit. After this `B` is removed and your history looks like this

```
A------B2'-------C''
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you. I've been searching how to remove B. It works fine.